# how to disable php8 jit at compile time?

Tags: php

how do i disable php8's new jit at compile time? on https://wiki.php.net/rfc/jit it was at least planned that the jit could be disabled at compile-time, but i haven't found any configure-options for this. fwiw i'm compiling php like this:

```bash
rm -rf php-src && \
git clone -b 'PHP-8.1' --depth 1 https://github.com/php/php-src.git && \
cd 'php-src' && \
./buildconf && \
CFLAGS='-s -Os -g0' ./configure --disable-all --disable-cgi --enable-cli --with-curl --with-libxml && \
make clean && \
make -j $(nproc) && \
rm -rfv ../php && \
cp -v ./sapi/cli/php ../php
```

Answer (score 0):

found it:

```
./configure --disable-opcache-jit --without-pcre-jit
```

.. found it by doing

```
./configure --help 2>&1 | grep -i jit
  --without-pcre-jit      Disable PCRE JIT functionality
  --disable-opcache-jit   Disable JIT
```

which i probably should have tried before asking.